# Limit of an Increasing Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm confident this is correct, but could you tell me if I'm missing something, or making any tacit assumptions that need making explicit?

Let $(a_n)$ be an increasing sequence with $a_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$. I claim that $a-a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$.

Since $(a_n)$ is increasing, $a_{n+1} \ge a_n$ for all $n$ and hence, by induction, $a_m \ge a_n$ for all $m \ge n$.

Taking the limit as $m \to \infty$ gives $a \ge a_n$, and hence $a-a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks Brian. I'm not assuming anything that I haven't mentioned, am I?

Comment: No, it’s fine. You *could* make it more rigorous. Suppose that some $a-a_n<0$, and let $\epsilon=a_n-a$. Then your induction shows that $|a_m-a|\ge\epsilon$ for all $m\ge n$, contradicting the fact that $a$ is the limit of the sequence.

Comment: The limit $a$ is $sup{a_n,n\in \mathbb N$